# How do I return a single attribute of a JSON response in Angular?

Tags: angular

I have multiple HTTP Requests to fetch data. Previously I was getting JSON responses which looked something like this :

```
[{"date":"25-04-2019 11:11:23","action":"Created Request","userName":"chaitanya"},{"date":"25-04-2019 11:13:18","action":"Edited Request","userName":"chaitanya"}]
```

Now the JSON responses look something like this :

```
{
    "status": "SUCCESS",
    "data": "[{\"date\":\"04-06-2019 05:51:33\",\"action\":\"Created Request\",\"userName\":\"David Katz\"},{\"date\":\"04-06-2019 05:53:43\",\"action\":\"Edited Request\",]",
    "errorMsg": null
}
```

Basically the earlier response is now part of "data" in the new JSON.

My previous return statement looked something like this :

```
return this.http.post('https://abc.xzu/fetchData', details)
```

How do I return the value of "data" in the new JSON? How do I access it?

Also, I have some other services as well which use subscribe or toPromise. What will be the change for them? Basically, I can't figure out how to access the value of "data" inside the new JSON.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can acces the data using:

```
 .subscribe( (result: any) => {
        this.data = result.data
    });
```

Comment: Or `return this.http.post('https://abc.xzu/fetchData', details).pipe(mergeMap(res => res.data));` then subscribe as usual.

Comment: Is also an option, but with your case you will not be able to get `status` or `errorMsg` if you want to.

Comment: I tried this but it's not working. I tried to log result.data and I get undefined for that. I changed it to result.json().data and I'm able to see it when I log it but when I try to access it in my HTML code, I get an error saying only arrays and iterables are allowed

Comment: My bad. I was getting a string in that "data" attribute rather than a JSON. Thanks Ronald. This worked for me!

Answer (score 1):

do you have a Response in your return at your API? something like:
Response.Status.....

This might be the issue.

or try to add to detail `.toString` or `.Stringefy`

Answer (score 1):

You can either do as [Ronald Haan](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56772805/3456021) stated (which means modifying your subscriptions) or something like this

```js
yourMethod() {
  return this.http.post('https://abc.xzu/fetchData', details)
    .pipe(
      tap(res => handleStatus(res)), // Handle errors without modifying the data
      mergeMap(res => res.data),
      mergeMap(data => JSON.parse(data)) // If you need to parse the JSON string
  );
}

handleStatus(res: {status: string, data: string, errorMsg: string | null}) {
  // Do something with 'status' and 'errorMsg'
}
```

This way you can handle the new fields and not change your subscriptions.

Answer (score 0):

```
url = "api/uddl/zxcc";

    getDataWithObservable(): Observable<CLASS[]> {
        return this.http.get(this.url)
           .map(this.extractData)
           .catch(this.handleErrorObservable);
    }
```